# Doesen't show Data

Tags: php, html, apache, mysqli

I'm trying to select and display some info about a record from my database.
After selecting the user/name/record and pressing Afiseaza (submit), the page remains the same, like not refreshing.

I can't find the problem. Here is  my code:

```
<?php 
include 'ch20_include.php'; 
doDB(); 

    if('!_POST')  { 
    //Arata 
        $display_block = "<h1>Alege un Elev</h1>"; 
    //Primeste partile 
        $get_list_sql = "SELECT id,CONCAT_WS(', ', nume,p_nume) AS display_name FROM nume_principal ORDER BY p_nume,nume"; 
        $get_list_res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$get_list_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

        if (mysqli_num_rowS($get_list_res) < 1) { 
        //Nici un elev 
        $display_block .= "<p><em>Scuze,nu a fost selectat nici un Elev!</em></p>"; 
        } else { 
        //Afiseaza 
        $display_block .= " 
        <form method=\"post\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\"/> 
        <p><label for=\"sel_id\">Alege un Elev:</label><br/> 
        <select id='sel_id\' name=\"sel_id\" required=\"required\">
        <option value=\"\">--Alege--</option>"; 

        while ($recs = mysqli_fetch_array($get_list_res))  { 
        $id = $recs['id']; 
        $display_name = stripslashes($recs['display_name']); 
        $display_block .= "<option value=\"".$id."\">".$display_name."</option>"; 
        } 
        $display_block .= " </select> <button type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"view\">Afiseaza\"></button> 
    </form> ";  
        } 
        //rezultate 
        mysqli_free_result($get_list_res);  

    } else if($_POST)  { 
        //Verifica field 
        if ($_POST['sel_id'] == "")   { 
            header("Location: seldata.php"); 
            exit; 
        } 
        //Versiune sigura ID 
        $safe_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['sel_id']);
        $get_nume_sql = "SELECT concat_ws(' ',p_nume,nume) as display_name FROM nume_principal WHERE id = '".$safe_id."'"; 
        $get_nume_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_nume_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

        while ($nmae_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_nume_res)) { 
            $display_name = stripslashes($name_info['display_name']); 
        } 
        $display_block = "<h1>Arata Informatile pentru ".$display_name."</h1>"; 

            mysqli_free_result($get_nume_res); 
        //Adresa 
            $get_adresele_sql = "SELECT adresa,oras,judet,cod_postal FROM adress WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'"; 
            $get_adresele_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_adresele_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));  

            if (mysqli_num_rows($get_adresele_res) > 0) { 
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Adresa:</strong><br/><ul>"; 

            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_adresele_Res))  { 
            $adresa = stripslashes($add_info['adresa']); 
            $oras = stripslashes($add_info['oras']); 
            $judet = stripslashes($add_info['oras']); 
            $cod_postal = stripslashes($add_info['cod_postal']); 

            $display_block .= "<li>$adresa,$oras,$judet,$cod_postal</li>";
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
            } 
            mysqli_free_result($get_adresele_res);  
            //telefon 
            $get_tel_sql = "SELECT tel_numar,type FROM telefon WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'"; 
            $get_tel_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_tel_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

            if (mysqli_num_rows($get_tek_res) > 0) { 
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Telefon:</stron><br/> <ul>"; 

            while ($tel_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_tel_res))  { 
            $tel_numar = stripslashes($tel_info['tel_numar']); 
            $tel_type = $tel_info['type']; 
            }
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
            }
            mysqli_free_result($get_tel_res); 
            //Adresele toate 
            $get_biologie_sql = "SELECT notab_1, notab_2, notab_3, notab_4, notab_5, medieb FROM biologie   WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'";  
            $get_biologie_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_biologie_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
            if (mysqli_num_rows($get_biologie_res) > 0 ) {   
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Note-Biologie:</strong><br/> <ul>";
            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_biologie_res)) { 
            $notab_1 = stripslashes($add_info['notab_1']); 
            $notab_2 = stripslashes($add_info['notab_2']); 
            $notab_3 = stripslashes($add_info['notab_3']); 
            $notab_4 = stripslashes($add_info['notab_4']); 
            $notab_5 = stripslashes($add_info['notab_5']); 
            $medieb = stripslashes($add_info['medieb']); 
            $display_block .= "<li>$notab_1 $notab_2 $notab_3 $notab_4 $notab_5 $medieb </li>"; 
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
             } 
                mysqli_free_result($get_biologie_res);   

                $get_chimie_sql = "SELECT notac_1, notac_2, notac_3, notac_4, notac_5, mediec FROM chimie   WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'";  
                $get_chimie_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_chimie_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

                if (mysqli_num_rows($get_chimie_res) > 0 ) {   
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Note-Chimie:</strong><br/> <ul>";
            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_chimie_res)) { 
            $notac_1 = stripslashes($add_info['notac_1']); 
            $notac_2 = stripslashes($add_info['notac_2']); 
            $notac_3 = stripslashes($add_info['notac_3']); 
            $notac_4 = stripslashes($add_info['notac_4']); 
            $notac_5 = stripslashes($add_info['notac_5']); 
            $mediec = stripslashes($add_info['mediec']); 
            $display_block .= "<li>$notac_1 $notac_2 $notac_3 $notac_4 $notac_5 $mediec </li>"; 
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
             } 
                mysqli_free_result($get_chimie_res);   

                $get_fizica_sql = "SELECT notaf_1, notaf_2, notaf_3, notaf_4, notaf_5, medief FROM fizica   WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'";  
                $get_fizica_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_fizica_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

                if (mysqli_num_rows($get_fizica_res) > 0 ) {   
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Note-Fizica:</strong><br/> <ul>";
            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_fizica_res)) { 
            $notaf_1 = stripslashes($add_info['notaf_1']); 
            $notaf_2 = stripslashes($add_info['notaf_2']); 
            $notaf_3 = stripslashes($add_info['notaf_3']); 
            $notaf_4 = stripslashes($add_info['notaf_4']); 
            $notaf_5 = stripslashes($add_info['notaf_5']); 
            $medief = stripslashes($add_info['medief']); 
            $display_block .= "<li>$notaf_1 $notaf_2 $notaf_3 $notaf_4 $notaf_5 $medief </li>"; 
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
             } 
                mysqli_free_result($get_fizica_res);   

                $get_franceza_sql = "SELECT notafr_1, notafr_2, notafr_3, notafr_4, notafr_5, mediefr FROM franceza     WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'";  
                $get_franceza_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_franceza_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
                if (mysqli_num_rows($get_franceza_res) > 0 ) {   
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Note-Franceza:</strong><br/> <ul>";
            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_franceza_res)) { 
            $notafr_1 = stripslashes($add_info['notafr_1']); 
            $notafr_2 = stripslashes($add_info['notafr_2']); 
            $notafr_3 = stripslashes($add_info['notafr_3']); 
            $notafr_4 = stripslashes($add_info['notafr_4']); 
            $notafr_5 = stripslashes($add_info['notafr_5']); 
            $mediefr = stripslashes($add_info['mediefr']); 
            $display_block .= "<li>$notafr_1 $notafr_2 $notafr_3 $notafr_4 $notafr_5 $mediefr </li>"; 
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
             } 
                mysqli_free_result($get_franceza_res); 


                $get_germana_sql = "SELECT notag_1, notag_2, notag_3, notag_4, notag_5, medieg FROM germana     WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'";  
                $get_germana_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_germana_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

                if (mysqli_num_rows($get_germana_res) > 0 ) {   
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Note-Germana:</strong><br/> <ul>";
            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_germana_res)) { 
            $notag_1 = stripslashes($add_info['notag_1']); 
            $notag_2 = stripslashes($add_info['notag_2']); 
            $notag_3 = stripslashes($add_info['notag_3']); 
            $notag_4 = stripslashes($add_info['notag_4']); 
            $notag_5 = stripslashes($add_info['notag_5']); 
            $medieg = stripslashes($add_info['medieb']); 
            $display_block .= "<li>$notag_1 $notag_2 $notag_3 $notag_4 $notag_5 $medieg </li>"; 
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
             } 
                mysqli_free_result($get_germana_res);   

                $get_informatica_sql = "SELECT notai_1, notai_2, notai_3, notai_4, notai_5, mediei FROM informatica WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'";  
                $get_informatica_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_informatica_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

                if (mysqli_num_rows($get_informatica_res) > 0 ) {   
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Note-Informatica:</strong><br/> <ul>";
            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_informatica_res)) { 
            $notai_1 = stripslashes($add_info['notai_1']); 
            $notai_2 = stripslashes($add_info['notai_2']); 
            $notai_3 = stripslashes($add_info['notai_3']); 
            $notai_4 = stripslashes($add_info['notai_4']); 
            $notai_5 = stripslashes($add_info['notai_5']); 
            $mediei = stripslashes($add_info['mediei']); 
            $display_block .= "<li>$notai_1 $notai_2 $notai_3 $notai_4 $notai_5 $mediei </li>"; 
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
             } 
                mysqli_free_result($get_matematica_res);   

                $get_matematica_sql = "SELECT notam_1, notam_2, notam_3, notam_4, notam_5, mediem FROM matematica   WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'";  
                $get_matematica_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_matematica_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

                if (mysqli_num_rows($get_matemtica_res) > 0 ) {   
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Note-Matematica:</strong><br/> <ul>";
            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_matematica_res)) { 
            $notam_1 = stripslashes($add_info['notam_1']); 
            $notam_2 = stripslashes($add_info['notam_2']); 
            $notam_3 = stripslashes($add_info['notam_3']); 
            $notam_4 = stripslashes($add_info['notam_4']); 
            $notam_5 = stripslashes($add_info['notam_5']); 
            $mediem = stripslashes($add_info['mediem']); 
            $display_block .= "<li>$notam_1 $notam_2 $notam_3 $notam_4 $notam_5 $mediem </li>"; 
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
             } 
                mysqli_free_result($get_matematica_res);   

                $get_romana_sql = "SELECT notar_1, notar_2, notar_3, notar_4, notar_5, medier FROM romana   WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'";  
                $get_romana_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_romana_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

                if (mysqli_num_rows($get_romana_res) > 0 ) {   
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Note-Romana:</strong><br/> <ul>";
            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_romana_res)) { 
            $notar_1 = stripslashes($add_info['notar_1']); 
            $notar_2 = stripslashes($add_info['notar_2']); 
            $notar_3 = stripslashes($add_info['notar_3']); 
            $notar_4 = stripslashes($add_info['notar_4']); 
            $notar_5 = stripslashes($add_info['notar_5']); 
            $medier = stripslashes($add_info['medier']); 
            $display_block .= "<li>$notar_1 $notar_2 $notar_3 $notar_4 $notar_5 $medier </li>"; 
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
             } 
                mysqli_free_result($get_romana_res);   

                $get_religie_sql = "SELECT notare_1, notare_2, notare_3, notare_4, notare_5, mediere FROM religie   WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'";  
                $get_religie_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_religie_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

                if (mysqli_num_rows($get_religie_res) > 0 ) {   
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Note-Religie:</strong><br/> <ul>";
            while ($add_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_religie_res)) { 
            $notare_1 = stripslashes($add_info['notare_1']); 
            $notare_2 = stripslashes($add_info['notare_2']); 
            $notare_3 = stripslashes($add_info['notare_3']); 
            $notare_4 = stripslashes($add_info['notare_4']); 
            $notare_5 = stripslashes($add_info['notare_5']); 
            $mediere = stripslashes($add_info['medieb']); 
            $display_block .= "<li>$notare_1 $notare_2 $notare_3 $notare_4 $notare_5 $mediere </li>"; 
            } 
            $display_block .= "</ul>"; 
             } 
                mysqli_free_result($get_religie_res);   

                //Nota personala 
            $get_notes_sql = "SELECT note FROM nota_personala WHERE nume_id = '".$safe_id."'"; 
            $get_notes_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_notes_sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

            if (mysqli_num_rows($get_notes_res) == 1) { 
            while ($note_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_notes_res)) { 
                $note = n12br(stripslashes($note_info['note'])); 
            }
            $display_block .= "<p><strong>Nota personala:</strong><br/> $note</p>"; 
            }
            mysqli_free_result($get_notes_res); 

            $display_block .= "<br/>
            <p style=\"text-align:center\"> 
            <a href=\"".$_server['PHP_SELF']."\">Alege altul</a></p>"; 
        }
        mysqli_close($mysqli); 
        ?> 
        <!DOCTYPE   html> 
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Elevii</title> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
        <?php echo $display_block; ?> 
        </body> 
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you just show it on fiddle so that we can check

Comment: No i don't get any error at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code is wrong !_POST can not use like a string because

"if return true for any non zero element"

, So change it

```
if(!$_POST)  or  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST')
```